# Why is this shapefile "flattened"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3

I'm working in ArcGIS 10.3. I have a shapefile, called chunk6, that looks flattened but can be viewed normally when merged with another similar shapefile (called chunk5).

In its own data frame, chunk6 it looks like this

[image]

In the data frame of chunk5, I can't see chunk6 unless it is merged with chunk 5. Below I can only see chunk5 even though chunk6 is also selected

[image]

Here I have merged chunk5 and chunk6 which produced the shapefile called chunk6_Merge. In the merged shapefile I can now see both chunk6 and chunk5 in the chunk6_Merge shapefile

[image]

Any idea why chunk6 is flattened when viewed by itself?

Note that both shapefiles have a a defined geographic coordinate system (GCS_South_American_1969) and are not projected.

Comment: I have had a similar problem with a point file that had points beyond the accepted coordinates for that coordinate system. For example, using WGS84, there were points at 150 N and 400 W. This does not make any sense in WGS84, and the display of the entire thing looked very strange: basically, a line, similar to yours. Not sure if this is the case here, or why it displays after merging, but perhaps check if any of the features were digitized incorrectly. Are any features beyond the bounding box of that coordinate system?

Comment: Index files messed up? Try to remove *.sb*